# append two elements from list to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having an empty list and a list which contains elements. Suppose

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []
```

I want to append the first two elements from `list1` to `list2`. How can I do that?

```
i=0;
prefetch.append(missData[i])
print(prefetch)
```

I have been trying this but this gives error index out of range.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: If you get an out of range error on this code, `missData` is definitively an empty list.

Comment: Don't think this is python. No `;` is required at end of line.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = list1[:2]
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []
list2.extend(list1[:2])
print("list2: {}".format(list2))
```

Output

```
list2: [1, 2]
```

As the name suggests, [extend()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/extend) method simply extends the list by appending elements into it.